# How To Vlookup Values in Diffrent Sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

[image]

I want to Apply This Vloopkup Function in sheet 1 but i have my data in sheet2 (Refer Screenshot)

[image]

As in Screenshot 2 You can see i am giving reference of sheet2 in vlookup function but its not working .below is the function i use, it is working in same sheet but now with different sheet

```
=VLOOKUP($D$1,Sheet2!$A$1:$B$4,2,0)
```

Comment: D1 is empty in sheet1...that is the reason for the #n/A error

Comment: Ya but it is present in sheet 2,i want this function to refer from sheet2

Comment: Just add `Sheet2!$D$1` instead of `$D$1`. You have done this for half the formula, not sure why you didn't for this bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to have the check value in and lookup range in sheet2 but the result in sheet1...you should reference the value range by reference to sheet as well..

```
=vlookup(sheet2!$D$1,sheet2!$A$1:$b$4,2,0)
```

Comment: Thanks Sivaprasath V .